# Best way to re-partition boot partions

Tags: partitioning

I am unable to install updates because there is not enough space on my boot partition.  But I noticed the following:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                    237M  187M   38M  84% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
```

Looks like `/dev/sda1` for the efi partition has way more than it needs while `/dev/sda2` for the boot partition is insufficient.

Is there a way to re-balance these partitions without re-installing from scratch?

If re-installing is the only option, where during installation can a specify better sizes so that this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Should have mentioned, this is Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manipulate the partition sized using gparted.  If it's not yet installed, you can install it with:
sudo apt-get install gparted